# How to resize pictures correctly with Wordpress Gallery Code?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, gallery

I'm using wordpress native gallery for showing picture gallery. http://codex.wordpress.org/Gallery_Shortcode
My problem is in the gallery for thumbnail , it doesn't show the full picture. It **cuts** small part of the picture and shows as thumbnail in the gallery. When I click on the picture it shows me the full version. 
I uploaded two states for you to understand better
[image]

[image]

As you see the full picture is not same as the thumbnail.
How can I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wordpress crops small thumbnails by default. To change this behaviour, go to:

Settings -> Media, and uncheck Crop thumbnail to exact dimensions (normally thumbnails are proportional). Watch out as this will mean that your new thumbnail will not fix exactly into 150x150px box.

To regenerate your thumbnails you can use: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/ regenerate plugin.